# Github branch is ahead by 5 commits, how to fix?

Tags: git, github

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Allen\Documents\GitHub\project2-pd7 [master]> git status
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 5 commits.
#
nothing to commit, working directory clean
C:\Users\Allen\Documents\GitHub\project2-pd7 [master]> git push
Counting objects: 36, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (15/15), done.
Writing objects: 100% (30/30), 3.93 KiB, done.
Total 30 (delta 8), reused 1 (delta 0)
error: unpack failed: index-pack abnormal exit
To https://github.com/stuycs-ml7/project2-pd7.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (unpacker error)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/stuycs-ml7/project2-pd7.git'
```

I'm still trying to find my sea legs with github, but these constant issues are killing me. Could anyone explain the solution in normalspeak so I could understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some other student in your class pushed some revisions since your last checkout / pull.

As hd1 pointed out, your best bet is to either `git pull`, which will likely create a merge commit, after which you might have to explicitly `git commit` the merge.  I prefer `git pull --rebase` to linearaize the changes before running `git push`

Run a `git log --graph` from the command line to get a good visualization of the current state of your local repository.

Do a `git fetch` to pull down the remote branch without trying to merge or rebase your current changes.  This will allow you to inspect the state of the remote repository with `git log --graph origin/master`

Comment: git pull returns already up-to-date. I'm not sure what you mean by commit the merge, so I just entered (git add .) and (git commit -m "") . I think I did sometime wrong because now it says:
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 6 commits.

Answer (score 2):

Your history has diverged from the history of the remote branch. Probably somebody has pushed commits to the remote branch since your last `git pull`. The solution is either:

```
git pull
```

or

```
git pull --rebase
```

The later tries to rewrite your commits so that they appear at the tip of the branch, rebased on top of the history of the remote branch. The former does a simple merge between your history of the history of the remote branch.

Answer (score 0):

Try `git pull` before you `git push`?

Comment: git pull returns:    merge made with 'recursive' strategy